# How can I make a simple firefox extension which can call a python script?

Tags: python, firefox

There is a website that I frequently go to  and play a browser game. I want to be able to have some kind of firefox plugin that can scrape data off of the page and send it to a python script. I want the controls for the program (toggle on/off) to be a HTML display which is added on to the webpage after every time I load it.

I am aware of plugins like Greasemonkey, but I don't want to use this because if I want to send any data to python, I have to setup a python http server and manually launch it every time I want to use my program.

Essentially this is what I want to be able to do:

1. Open Firefox as I would normally to do any kind of internet browsing
2. Go to the website which has my game.
3. The game is loaded, javascript code is executed which adds some basic HTML controls which can be used to toggle settings in my backend python program
4. If I choose to enable the program, javascript will parse the page when necessary and send that data to a python script on my machine.
5. The python program executes, recieves the data, and does what I want.

I feel like this should be a simple task, but I can't find anything straightforward. From what I have been reading, I can make a Firefox extension which can do this, but the tutorials I have seen are all for things like adding extra features to the browser. I just want a minimal tutorial since all I need to do is just run my own javascript when visiting website "X" and then call a python script.